# Two simultaneous users logged in at the same time in Meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to create functionality similar to that of Twitter, where you can be logged into more than one account at the same time.

However, Meteor (because of it's reactivity) does not allow one to log a user in immediately after logging the current user out, and to my knowledge I can't have two active User sessions at the same time.

This is what I tried to do, and that **does not work**:

```
'submit .switchUsersForm': function(event) {
    var password = event.target.email.value;
    var email = event.target.email.value;

    //log out current user
    Meteor.logout(function(err){
        if (err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Logout failed");
        }
    })

    //immediately log other user in
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('These credentials are not valid.');
        } else {
            Router.go('home');
        }
    });
}
```

Has anyone worked out a solution for this particular functionality in Meteor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine this would work if you called `loginWithPassword` from **within** the logout callback. As it is now, `logout` will start running, and then `loginWithPassword` will execute immediately without waiting for `logout` to complete. Try something like this:

```
Meteor.logout(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    throw new Meteor.Error("Logout failed");
  }
  else {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(...);
  }
});
```

And to answer your other question, you can't have two users logged in at the same time in the same browser. You can use incognito mode, and or open a different browser (FF, Safari, etc.).

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking to the original code, this approach worked. 

Thanks!